# Render object of objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, object, render, ngfor

How I could render an object of objects in Angular but without turn it in an array or anything similar. The reason for this is that I have a large object of objects and I would like to avoid to many iterations from object to an array after that to loop the array in the html.

For example I have:

```
    persons: any = {
      0: { name: 'name1', email: 'name1@gmail.com' },
      1: { name: 'name2', email: 'name2@gmail.com' },
      2: { name: 'name3', email: 'name3@gmail.com' }
    }
```

When I do is the following:

```
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons | keyvalue">
      <p>
      {{ person.key }} / {{ person.value }}
      </p>
    </div>
```

The result is:

```
    0 / [object Object]
    1 / [object Object]
    2 / [object Object]
```

I tried to loop one more time thru the person.value:

```
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons | keyvalue;">
      <p>
      {{ person.key }}
      <span *ngFor="let item of person.value | keyvalue"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
```

but this causing an error ("No overload matches this call.").

Could anyone tell me how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `json` pipe

example:

```html
{{persons | json}}
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gu5ggl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I don't need exactly this but the example that you provided in the comment of Jeremy Thille is working and it is exactly what I tried to do. I tried with {{ person.value.name }} but the correct way was {{ person.value['name'] }}. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `keyvalue` pipe transforms `0: { name: 'name1', email: 'name1@gmail.com' }` into `{ key : 0, value : { name: 'name1', email: 'name1@gmail.com' }}`. So you should be able to do :

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons | keyvalue">
   <p>
      {{ person.value.name}} / {{ person.value.email }}
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nhwejf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I already tried this but forgot to mention it. The result is an error.

Comment: In the example that eko provided it is working:
 <p>{{ person.value['name'] }} / {{ person.value['email'] }}</p>

Thanks